# Insert or Update or Delete Data From Table Value Parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a ProductsAttributesValues table which have,

```
Id   ProductId   AttributeId   Value   ORDER
-------------------------------------------------
```

A product with an attribute(same ProductId/AttributeId) can have multiple values but with different orders. I have a type,

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[ProductsAttributesValuesType] AS TABLE
(
    [AttributeId] [INT],
    [Value] [NVARCHAR](MAX)
)
```

I am passing this `ProductsAttributesValuesType` in my stored-procedure as table-value-parameter with ProductId parameter. Now what I need seems very simple but I am stuck. The information in the `ProductsAttributesValuesType` is coming from a UI. So,

1) If a value is null or empty or white-space then I need to do nothing and delete all the existing records from `ProductsAttributesValues` with same ProductId/AttributeId.

2) If a value is not null or non-empty or non-white-space then there might be a single value or multiple values(multiple records in `ProductsAttributesValuesType`). If there is single value I need to insert if no existing value exist and update if value exist. If there are multiple values(multiple records in `ProductsAttributesValuesType`) I need to insert all values if no existing value exist and update/insert if value exist.

One way is to simply delete all `ProductsAttributesValues` tables with same ProductId/AttributeId. Then Insert values with non null values. But I think it is not very efficient.

**Update:** Currently, I am deleting first all multi-values attributes-values. next, I am deleting all attributes-values where values are empty. Next, I am inserting/updating single value attributes-values. Next, I am inserting multi-valeus attributes-values.

Comment: I know about MERGE but I am stuck. Can you please solve this issue?

Comment: Include what you have tried so far and an example set of source/results.

Comment: I think the the method you describe in the last paragraph would probably lead to the cleanest code.  I wouldn't worry about performance.  The difference between a few updates versus delete/inserts is not going to be that great.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, Thanks for your expert openion

Answer (score 5):

Avoid using Merge statement break it down to Three statement and wrap it all in one Transaction as follows

```
CREATE  Procedure Upserting_To_ProductsAttributesValues 
@ProductsAttributesValuesType   [dbo].[ProductsAttributesValuesType] READONLY
AS 
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;
 BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

-- Delete values 
  DELETE FROM ProductsAttributesValues 
  FROM ProductsAttributesValues T INNER JOIN @ProductsAttributesValuesType P
  ON T.AttributeId = P.AttributeId
  WHERE P.Value IS NULL OR RTRIM(LTRIM(P.Value)) = ''

-- Update Statement 
UPDATE T
SET T.Value = P.Value
FROM ProductsAttributesValues T INNER JOIN @ProductsAttributesValuesType P
ON T.AttributeId = P.AttributeId

-- Insert Statement
INSERT INTO ProductsAttributesValues (AttributeId, Value)
SELECT AttributeId, Value
FROM @ProductsAttributesValuesType P
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM ProductsAttributesValues
                  WHERE AttributeId = P.AttributeId)

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;  --<-- If nothing went wrong
 END TRY

 BEGIN CATCH


     -- Now make use of ERROR Functions to get detailed information
     -- about the error, these functions are only allowed in catch block

 SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE() AS [ERROR_MESSAGE]
       ,ERROR_LINE()    AS [ERROR_LINE]
       ,ERROR_NUMBER()  AS [ERROR_NUMBER] 
 END CATCH

END
```

*Note*

The reason I suggested to avoid Merge statement see this article By Aaron Bertrand  [`Use Caution with SQL Server's MERGE Statement`](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/)

Comment: Thanks Ali but I have multiple values.

Comment: This should work, but in DELETE part, you want to say LEFT JOIN not INNER JOIN